# Exceptional isomorphisms of classical algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, permutations

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p\geq 0$. An affine algebraic group $G$ is an affine variety over $k$ with a group structure such that multiplication and inversion are morphisms of varieties.

A simple algebraic groups is defined to have no non-trivial connected normal subgroup (it may have center, but finite!)

We have a classification of simple algebraic groups in terms of the Dynkin diagrams:

1. Classical: $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$;
2. Exceptional: ...

The following equalities of Dynkin diagrams are clear:

- $A_1=B_1=C_1$;
- $B_2=C_2$;
- $A_3=D_3$;
- $A_1\times A_1=D_2$

My question is: can we write explicit isomorphisms between small rank classical groups? (not necessary simple)

It is very easy to show $\mathrm{Sp}_2(k)=\mathrm{SL}_2(k)$ and $\mathrm{O}_2(k)\cong\mathrm{GL}_1(k).2$. (the previous symbols denote the special linear group, general linear group, symplectic group and orthogonal group).

For example, Exercise 1.8.19 in Geck "An intro to alg geom and alg groups" implies that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(k)\cong\mathrm{O}_3$, provided $p\neq2$, by constructing an explicit isomorphism (actually a surjective morphism whose kernes is $\{\pm1\}$).

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have asked whether we can write explicit isomorphisms of small rank classical groups...the answer is yes. Do you want a list of all isomorphisms of low rank classical groups?

Comment: Yes, the main aim of this question was to collect some explicit isomorphisms of low rank classical groups. Equally good would be to have some insights on how to explicitly construct some of them.

Comment: Not a clue! Also apologies for my rather aggressive sounding comment, I would very much like some insight into this myself.

Comment: No problem. These isomorphisms, for the finite groups, can be quite easily constructed (see for example Kleidman-Liebeck, 'The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups'), however in the proof they do use the finiteness of the groups; i.e. one constructs a mono/epi-morphism then notes that the two groups have the same order.

Comment: To be more precise about the Kleidman-Liebeck reference: see Proposition 2.9.1 (google books does have the relevant pages).